# <embed> tag src attribute for Youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm trying to get this result in the `src` attribute of the `embed` tag

Change: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXzz31otZ4w
To: http://www.youtube.com/v/IXzz31otZ4

```
 <object><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXzz31otZ4w" type="application/x-shockwave-     flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always"           allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>

 <script>
 var vid, code
 vid=document.getElementsByTagName('EMBED')[0];
 code=vid.src.slice(-11);
 vid.setAttribute("src","http://www.youtube.com/v/" + code)
 </script>
```

It seems to replace the `src` attribute, but the video isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your youtube ID is getting corrupted during the splice (in the example is missing letter "w" at the end)

This should work:

```
var vid, code;
vid=document.getElementsByTagName('EMBED')[0];
code = vid.src.match(/(^|&(?!amp;)|\\?)v=([^&]+)/);
if (code)
    vid.setAttribute("src","http://www.youtube.com/v/" + code[2])
```